# How to fix OutOfMemory with Cursor.getString()?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I read a String from Cursor:

```
String image = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(image));
```

It's crash with OutOfMemory exception. My "image" colum use to store image data which encoded by base64 (http://www.sveinbjorn.org/news/2005-11-28-02-39-23). Anybody can help me?

Comment: Is image is your image path or image it self ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting Image into String so you are getting a OutOfMemory exception.
You have to use inputStream reader insted of this.

For more information click here

```
http://sree.cc/google/storing-and-retriving-images-in-sqlite-database-in-android
```